# Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments with aggregate results

Tags: aggregateresult, math

I have object Deal__c and child object Deal_revenue__c related by the field Deal__c on on the child.
I want to find the remaining amount of unbooked total by the arithemtic function described below but my attempt to calculate the RemainingAmount throws the error:

> Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

```
     AggregateResult[] ActualizedAmount = [select SUM(Amount__c )sum from
 Deal_revenue__c where 
    date__c >: StartDate 
and Deal__c =: deal.id 
and Amount__c != NULL];

    Decimal ActualizedDecimal = (Decimal) ActualizedAmount[0].get('sum'); 

    Decimal RemainingAmount = deal.Campaign_Amount__c - ActualizedAmount;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple typo on your part:

```
 Decimal RemainingAmount = deal.Campaign_Amount__c - ActualizedAmount // type=AggregateResult!
```

should be

```
 Decimal RemainingAmount = deal.Campaign_Amount__c - ActualizedDecimal
```